# seamless-immutable: Detect Immutable object with plain old javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, seamless-immutable

I'm using [seamless immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) library for my Redux application. In some situation, I need to check if given object is a seamless-immutable object or just only plain old javascript object. I have read document but I haven't seen any related document about this. Please tell me how to check by code.

Thanks

Comment: there are no seamless immutable objects. seamless changes the property descriptor and makes all properties non-configurable and non-writable. But it adds a flag to the objects it has modified, and you can check for it with `Immutable.isImmutable()`

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your help. :D I have searched before, but all results leads to isImmutable of `immutable.js` (not seamless-immutable) :D So I don't think it works at that time. Can you please post as an answer so I can accept that. thanks

Comment: `Immutable.isImmutable()` [implementation](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/blob/master/src/seamless-immutable.js#L58-L68) and [export](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/blob/master/src/seamless-immutable.js#L713)